# How can I use a serializer to retrieve data from a django model in a nested way?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django model with 3 fields: "product", "price_1" and "price_2".

I would like to serialize this model in a way that the result would be:

```
{
   "product": "some product",
   "price": {
      "price_1": 15.00,
      "price_2": 25.00
   }
}
```

I was able to reach this result by creating a model for the price and connecting it to the product model with a foreign key.

```
#Models

class Product(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField()
   price = models.ForeignKey(Price)

class Price(models.Model):
   price_1 = models.FloatField()
   price_2 = models.FloatField()

#Serializers

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Price
      fields = ['price_1', 'price_2']

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   price = PriceSerializer()

   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = [
         "product", 
         "price",
      ]
```

It worked, but it's very ineffective. Is there a way for me to achieve the same result, but having only one model such as:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField()
   price_1 = models.FloatField()
   price_2 = models.FloatField()
```

And it would be even better if I could have only the numbers without the word "price":

```
{
   "product": "some product",
   "price": {
      1: 15.00,
      2: 25.00
   }
}
```

Although the second result is better, I'd already be very happy if I could achieve the first one using only one model.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is the view I'm using:

```
class ProductReadAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

Comment: Can you share the ModelViewSet?

Comment: `1: ` and `2:` are not valid JSON: the keys of a JSON object is always a string, so `"1"`, `"2"`, etc., but not `1` or `2`.

Comment: I added the View as well. Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`source` [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument to pass the entire object to a nested serializer which will handle only the price fields to do this.

**models**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField()
   price_1 = models.FloatField()
   price_2 = models.FloatField()
```

**serializers**:

```
class ProductPriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = ['price_1', 'price_2']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   price = ProductPriceSerializer(source='*')

   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = [
         "product",
      ]
```

Getting `1` or `2` as keys would be a little more difficult and I refrain from doing that as it would be somewhat hacky. But moving further it appears your model schema (both of them) is not normalized, in fact it is better for you to have different models in case you have multiple prices to handle, the below code would be better modelling for your use case:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   product = models.CharField()


class Price(models.Model):
   price = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   price = models.FloatField()  # use a DecimalField instead for prices!
```

Comment: Thank you. This explanation was really helpful!